# Disable hl-line-mode at startup

Tags: highlighting, hl-line-mode

Something turned hl-line-mode on, which is painful to look at with my color theme.

I've added this to my .emacs

```
(hl-line-mode -1)
(global-hl-line-mode -1)
```

to no avail.

I've tried commenting out *everything* in my .emacs, but the highlighting still happens.

I can disable it with

```
M-x hl-line-mode
```

but I need to do that every time I visit a file.

How can I find out what's enabling it, and how can i disable it for good?

Comment: Start with **no** init file (`emacs -Q`) and recursively bisect it to isolate the code.

Comment: @Dan Well, w/o even bisecting anything (let alone recursively ;)) a plain emacs WILL turn hl-line on in some places, most notably in recentf-open-files, where it is not only non-de-activatable, but also buggy :( So, yeah.

Comment: @Dan This does disable it, so there must be something else other than .emacs being run at startup. I'll look.

Comment: @yPhil I guess this is the time when I really learn how emacs init works from head to toe and say goodbye to about half of my headaches.

Comment: @broncoAbierto did you try to `recentf-open-files`? hard-coded `hl-line-mode` ; No way to turn it off :(

Comment: @yPhil Well, I just grepped and removed every mention of hl-line-mode from my packages in .emacs.d/elpa and nothing, still highlighting. Not fun.

Comment: yPhil: which version of Emacs? In Emacs 25.2.1 `recentf-open-files` (or indeed `recentf.el`) contains no call to `hl-line-mode` or any other instance of the text "hl-line".

Comment: I don't yet see any mention of starting Emacs with `emacs -Q`. I see only mention of "a plain emacs". Start with `emacs -Q` (no init file and no site file), to see if you can reproduce the problem. If the problem is from `recentf.el`, without your doing anything, then consider filing a bug against that: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew I have started with `emacs -Q` and the problem goes away, but I still haven't been able to find what triggers it.

Comment: In that case: (1) If the problem goes away also when you start with `emacs -q` (lowercase) then recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit. (2) If the problem does not go away with `emacs -q` but it does go away with `emacs -Q` then check `site-run-file` etc. - something is going wrong with your site's installation of Emacs. See the Emacs manual, node [Init File](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

Answer (score 0):

I actually was never able to find the culprit, but I got rid of it (at least mostly) nonetheless.

I realized it was not happening on all modes, so I ended up adding a hook for the ones it does show up in that I use the most. Perhaps it's a bit dirty, but it did the trick.

In case anyone's interested, this is what I put in my init file (notice the nil instead of a -1):

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq hl-line-mode nil)))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq hl-line-mode nil)))
```

Comment: Re: "I actually was never able to find the culprit". Did you try both `emacs -Q` and `emacs -q` to find out if it was your personal configuration or the system installation?

Comment: Yes. It goes away with both options, but I didn't find any package that set it on that I could neutralize.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than disable it, you could update its color using `set-face-attribute`.

The command `describe-face` shows the color of the thing at point and its inheritance structure.  I found it helpful to give this command a permanent keybinding:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h j") 'describe-face)
```

The `list-colors` command shows built in color names relative to your current theme.  You can use these together with `set-face-attribute` to find a color that works for you.

I use the `global-hl-line-mode` with the `tango-dark` theme whose default highlight is bright yellow.

```
(load-theme 'tango-dark)    
(global-hl-line-mode 1)

 ;; Define tolerable highlighting color
 (set-face-attribute 'highlight nil :background "#3e4446" :foreground 'unspecified)
```

This is what the above lines look like:

[image: Changing faces]

Comment: For whoever down-voted this, is there something technically incorrect about it?  I understand that it doesn't explain how to disable hl-line-mode.  However, the problem the OP had was that their hl-line was "painful to look at".  This answer addresses that problem.  Disabling hl-line simply happens to be another way to address the problem (and is somewhat of an XY issue).